# Probability of random variables converging

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1(x),X_2(x),\ldots ,X_n(x)$ be $n$ iid random variables. I know that 
$$\mathbf{P}(\lim_n X_n(x)=X(x))=1$$
for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We also know that the limit random variable $X$ is a.s. constant and considering $X\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, it is continuous. I want to show that 
$$\mathbf{P}(\lim_nX_n(x)=X(x)\ \text{ for all }x\in \mathbb{R})=1.$$
I thought about using countable additivity of probability on $\mathbb{Q}$ and then applying continuouty to extend the result to the whole $\mathbb{R}$. Since
$$\mathbf{P}(\lim_nX_n(x)\neq X(x)\ \text{ for all }x\in \mathbb{Q})=\sum_{x\in \mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{P}(X_n(x)\neq X(x))=0+0+\ldots.$$
Is there anything else I should add to this explanation? Ideas?

Comment: I should have mentioned that $X(x)$ is a a.s. constant random variable for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample.

Let $\Omega=\mathbb R$ be equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and a probability measure that gives value $0$ to singletons.

For every $n$ we define $X_n(x):\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by prescription $\omega\mapsto 1_{\{x\}}(\omega)$ and $X(x):\Omega\to\mathbb R$ by prescription $\omega\mapsto0$.

The $X_n$ are a.s. constant hence independent, and have equal probability with:$$\{\lim X_n(x)=X(x)\}=\mathbb R-\{x\}$$

So that: $$P(\{\lim X_n(x)=X(x)\})=P(\mathbb R-\{x\})=1$$

However: $$\bigcap_{x\in\mathbb R}\{\lim X_n(x)=0\}=\bigcap_{x\in\mathbb R}(\mathbb R-\{x\})=\varnothing$$

So that: $$P(\{\forall x\in\mathbb R[\lim X_n(x)=X(x)]\})=P(\varnothing)=0$$