# Almost surely convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1(x),X_2(x),\ldots ,X_n(x)$ be iid random variables. They are non-decreasing, piecewise linear, convex and they depend on a parameter $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We know that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ 
$$\mathbf{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(x)=X(x)\right)=1,$$
where $X$ is a constant for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, meaning it can be thought of as a function $X\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. I want to prove that then
$$\mathbf{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(x)=X(x), \ \text{for all }x\in \mathbb{R}\right)=1.$$
Problem is that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable. My thought is to choose a dense countable subset $\mathbb{Q}$ and from countable additivity we get
$$\mathbf{P}\left(\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{Q}} \lim_{n\to\infty} X_n(x)\neq X(x)\right)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Q}}\mathbf{P}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(x)\neq X(x)\right)=0+0+\ldots =0.$$
Since the limit of convex functions is continuous, we know that $X$ is continuous. Hence the convergence must also happen in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Is my explanation correct? Any ideas on how to improve it?

It is different from [Probability of random variables converging](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380282/probability-of-random-variables-converging) as $X_i$ are continuous.

Comment: @Did The OP added some conditions on the $X(x)$.

Comment: @drhab Still the same basic problems: what is a "non-decreasing, piecewise linear, convex" random variable? Are we to understand that $\Omega=\mathbb R$? Thus, $X_n:\Omega\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$? And so on. Note that reposting similar, almost identical, questions about rather involved problems, is not the way to go, especially if the differences are not even mentioned.